# Apache web logs "GET http/1.1" 200 error?

Tags: apache-2.2

I've got some puzzling (at least to me) errors that show up in my webserver logs. What's puzzling is that they show my error page being referenced, but that error page doesn't show up as being displayed in hits on statcounter.com. Can someone tell me the difference in these two kinds of errors? Or is only one a "real" error?

This is in WordPress, and I have my 404.php file in my theme redirecting to a static Wordpress page at mydomain.com/error/

These first two log entries show /error/, but a "hit" on my /error/ page doesn't show in my webstats. The page referenced - /2009/08/delete-preference-files/ - exists, and shows a "hit" at statcounter.

```
 92.17.232.242 - - [13/Mar/2010:01:45:43 -0800] "GET /error/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4012 
 "http://mydomain.com/2009/08/delete-preference-files/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows;U; 
Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100202 Firefox/3.5.8 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)" 732 4432

 92.17.232.242 - - [13/Mar/2010:01:47:11 -0800] "GET /error/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4012
 "http://mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/default/style.css" "Mozilla/5.0(Windows; U; 
Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100202 Firefox/3.5.8 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)" 861 4432
```

These are two error entries that display my /error/ page, because /error/ gets a "hit" in statcounter. The page /cookies/ doesn't exist.

```
72.174.16.202 - - [13/Mar/2010:10:53:37 -0800] "GET /cookies HTTP/1.1" 302 21 "-"
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6
 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)" 394 642

72.174.16.202 - - [13/Mar/2010:10:53:38 -0800] "GET /error/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4012 "-"
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 
(.NET CLR 3.5.30729)" 393 4432
```

Comment: The right way to do this is to create a 404 page template. You may be interested in visiting our sister site [wordpress.se] for further information on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, I'm there already: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/268/songdogtech Have made much progress in the years since I asked this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an error, it's a page called "/error/".  The 200 means it succeeded.